# Google Line Charts - GA look 'n feel

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to reproduce some of the Google Analitycs line charts styles with the [Google Chart lib](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

GA:

[image]

Google Line Chart:

[image]

There are 2 things that I'm struggling with reproducing:

- I can't find a way to fill the area below the line with a background color
- I did not find how to make the dots on the line to be always displayed (currently, I can display one of them when clicking on the line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using an Area Chart, not a Line Chart.  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart

For the points appearing on the line all the time, see Points documentation.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points

Just off the top of my head, here's some other settings of note (details for all of these appear at the bottom of the AreaChart documentation page):

```
var options = {
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
    alignment: 'start'
  },
  vAxis: {
    textPosition: 'in'
  },
  focusTarget: 'category' // if multiple lines, data for all appear in tooltip
};
```

Comment: I'll add something about the points for you when I'm on a computer instead of my cell phone, but the key word on the docs site is "Points" if you want to look it up yourself.